# xcrun: error while installing Regex on Mac OS

Tags: ios, python-3.x, regex, iphone, macos

I am running into the following error while installing regex on MAC OS.
Could you please help me on this?

```
Building wheels for collected packages: regex
    Building wheel for regex (setup.py) ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
    sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_c/wy_4gz0x7775tw9p1hpy41x99lls8j/T/pip-install-_s78j3ww/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_c/wy_4gz0x7775tw9p1hpy41x99lls8j/T/pip-install-_s78j3ww/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
  __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/_c/wy_4gz0x7775tw9p1hpy41x99lls8j/T/pip-wheel-rp2t5j6n
         cwd: /private/var/folders/_c/wy_4gz0x7775tw9p1hpy41x99lls8j/T/pip-install-_s78j3ww/regex/
     Complete output (17 lines):
     running bdist_wheel
     running build
     running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex
    running build_ext
    building 'regex._regex' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex_3
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/regex_3/_regex.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex
```